# How to avoid having void in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React and TypeScript.

```js
import React from 'react';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
interface PropsType {
  files: File
}
const ParsingFile:React.FC<PropsType> = ({files}) => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(emptyFile);
  const [rfile, setRfile] = React.useState<XLSX.WorkBook>();
  const readFile = (file:File) =>{
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e:any) => {
      const bstr = e!.target!.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
      setRfile(wb);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }

  return(
     <div>
       {readfile(file)} // this line
     </div>
   )
}
```

This throws error,

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'
The expected type comes from propeprty 'children' which is declared here on type
'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

But if I have it,

```js
<div>
  <React.Fragment>
    {readFile(file)}
  </React.Fragment>
</div>
```

It does not throw error.
Here are my questions,
1. why `void` function cannot be used alone?
2. how can I fix it without having other components?

Thanks in advance!
**EDIT**
Within this component(ParsingFile), I want to have a Reading excel file, Parsing and Writing new excel file.

Comment: If the function returns nothing, why even call it inside JSX?

Comment: Yeah, `readFile` needs to return JSX if you wanna use it there. What are trying to do anyway?

Comment: Inside JSX, I want to conduct 'reading excel file' process.

Comment: JSX is used to render HTML. If your function does not render anything, then its place is definitely not inside the template. You can call it inside the `render` function, yet not include it in the template.

Comment: I would suggest you move that kind of code into a separate module that just exposes the method for use, as opposed to mixing it in with UI related code.

Comment: ps. you should be reading it as an arrayBuffer and not as an binarystring

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the `readFile` method only needs to be run once, and it is to be run on initialisation of the component? In that case, I would recommend you to fully make use of react hooks.

The second argument in the `useEffect` hook takes in an empty array, which 'tells' your component that the effect does not depend on any other values, and will never need to be re-render. You may read more about this common React Hook optimisation technique over [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

```
const ParsingFile:React.FC<PropsType> = ({files}) => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(emptyFile);
  const [rfile, setRfile] = React.useState<XLSX.WorkBook>();

  useEffect(() => {
   readFile(file);
  }, []);

   const readFile = (file:File) =>{
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e:any) => {
      const bstr = e!.target!.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
      setRfile(wb);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }

  return(
     <div>
        // other content
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, by using `useEffect()`, `readFile` will be mounted to the component, right? So that, I don't need to have it inside JSX

Comment: @jayko03 that is right. It will be run on mount (the above technique is similar to `componentDidMount`).